Converting string to date in Polars
All,
Trying to use Polars in Python (latest versions) and can't seem to use the following that is shown in the documentation see api (polars.Expr.str.to_date):
s = pl.Series(["2020/01/01", "2020/02/01", "2020/03/01"])
s.str.to_date()

AttributeError: 'StringNameSpace' object has no attribute 'to_date'


Is this a problem with my installation or perhaps something else?
Thanks,
Jeff
I executed the statements:
s = pl.Series(["2020/01/01", "2020/02/01", "2020/03/01"])
s.str.to_date()
I expected then to be converted to date datatype.

What version number? (e.g. pl.__version__) How did you install Polars? Does s.str.strptime(pl.Date) work?

pl.version shows 0.16.13

The latest version of Polars is 0.20.30

s.str.strptime(pl.Date) seems to work ... so is it a version issue?so how would I convert a date on a dataframe assuming df is dataframe and 'Order Date' is column?

Yeah, it is a version issue. 0.16.13 appears to be from March 2023 and .str.to_date() was added later (as a simpler version of .str.strptime)  Do you mean .with_columns(pl.col("Order Date").str.strptime(pl.Date))? Perhaps you want to update your question to include a dataframe example.

Ok had to modify slightly to following:  df.with_columns(pl.col("Order Date").str.strptime(pl.Date, strict=False)) but it worked!!!   Thanks!

Here is an approach to this
import polars as pl

s = pl.Series(["2020/01/01", "2020/02/01", "2020/03/01"])

s = s.str.strptime(pl.Date, "%Y/%m/%d")

print(s)

which gives
shape: (3,)
Series: '' [date]
[
    2020-01-01
    2020-02-01
    2020-03-01
]

